# How to create Reduces for a custom Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I was working on a shopping website this morning, using React Typescript and Context API, and want to use React Reducers to manipulate my ***Shopping Cart*** State with the custom Types I created for the Product type, including an Items Array and some Functions ...
The problem is I don't know how to pass parameters with the Action in the CartReducer function, and would like to know how you would do it

***My CartContext***

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from "react-query";





type ICartContext = [IProductItem[] | undefined, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IProductItem[] | undefined>>];

export const CartContext = React.createContext<ICartContext>([[], () => null]);



type Action = "Add" | "Update" | "Remove"

const CartReducer = (state: IProductItem[], action: Action) => {

    return state
}


const CartProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({children}: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {

    const [cart, setCart] = React.useReducer(CartReducer, [], undefined)


    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={[cart, setCart]}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );

};

export default CartProvider;
```

***My Types***

```
interface IProductItem{
    id: number
    title: string
    description: string
    category: string
    image: string
    price: number
    quantity: number
}

type ProductType = {
    items: IProductItem[];
    saveItem: (item: IProductItem) => void
    updateItem: (id: number) => void
    removeItem: (id: number) => void
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as your action's type:

```
// each specific action includes a `type` property

interface AddAction {
  type: "Add";
  addedProduct: IProductItem;
}
interface UpdateAction {
  type: "Update";
  updatedProduct: IProductItem;
}
interface RemoveAction {
  type: "Remove";
  removedProduct: IProductItem;
}

// Action is a union of all the possible actions
type Action = AddAction | UpdateAction | RemoveAction;

const CartReducer = (state: IProductItem[], action: Action) => {
  // Since `type` is the only property all actions have in common,
  // it's the only property that can be accessed until narrowing
  // it with a condition or a switch statement

  switch (action.type) {
    case "Add":
      // can access action.addedProduct here
      return state;

    case "Update":
      // can access action.updatedProduct here
      return state;

    case "Remove":
      // can access action.removedProduct here
      return state;
  }
};

// elsewhere:
dispatch({ type: "Add", addedProduct: product })
```

Comment: Hello @Stephen Jennings, thanks for your answer I did what u told me but when I try to export the `setState`  in the Provider values I get the following error... how can i fix it : 
`Type 'Dispatch<Action>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<IProductItem[] | undefined>>'.
  Type 'SetStateAction<IProductItem[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Action'.ts(2322)`

Comment: I think that's coming from the type `ICartContext`, it probably needs to be updated to accept `Dispatch<Action>` instead of `Dispatch<SetStateAction<IProductItem[] | undefined>>`

Comment: Yes I corrected this yesterday it all works well now, thanks for your help.. Appreciate it